New bathtub faucet with diffuser has intermittent fast drip
I recently replaced an old bathtub faucet with diffuser which had a steady slow continuous drip. Now, instead, it has an intermittent fast drip with no drips in the times inbetween. I haven't got a good fix on the spacing between yet. Sometimes it seems like minutes and sometimes it seems like hours but in reality, I don't stand in the bathroom just waiting to document dripping. But when the house is quiet, I can usually hear when the fast dripping occurrs. It won't last long. Maybe a 20 seconds, if that. Initially, when I shut the water off, it takes a long time to stop with the fast dripping. I can speed up the process by playing with the diffuser lever(? pull thing) so that some water comes out really fast like a little stream for a few seconds. Then finally when it is done with all that is when it goes to the intermittent fast dripping. Any ideas?

This sounds like you have a problem with a valve that does not close 100%. The water is just dripping differently because of a different tub spout.

RMDman how do I figure that out?

Honestly, Marcy and meaning no disrespect,  if you have to ask me you are better off calling a plumber.   The spout does nothing to shut off the flow of water.
